# Tailwind nested declaration error with Nuxt application

Tags: vue.js, nested, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I am using Tailwind within a Nuxt application. I am trying to have some nested classes (using BEM syntaxe).

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";

.class1{
@apply someTailwindClasses
}
    
.class2{
@apply someTailwindClasses
}

.class3{
@apply someTailwindClasses
}

.class4 {
        @apply someTailwindClasses

    &__element1 {
        @apply someTailwindClasses
    }
}
```

I have this configuration in my nuxt.config.js file

```
const path = require('path')

export default {
  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: 'myTitle',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en'
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
      { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
    '~assets/css/tailwind.scss',
  ],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/tailwindcss
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
  ],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
  ],

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: {
        'postcss-import': {},
        'tailwindcss/nesting': {},
        'postcss-nested': {},
        tailwindcss: path.resolve(__dirname, './tailwind.config.js')
      }
    },
    preset: {
      stage: 1 // see https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#future-css-featuress
    }
  }
}
```

My package.json files has those dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.15.1",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.7",
    "postcss-nesting": "^8.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^4.2.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.3.4",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8.3.6",
    "postcss-import": "^14.0.2",
    "postcss-nested": "^5.0.6",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.15"
  }
```

I have this error about a declaration in the middle of a long list of declarations `assets/css/tailwind.scss:85:1`, not even from the beginning (as if it was complaining about `.class3`). If I remove the nested declaration (`.class4`) then it's fine. The nesting is the problem.

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@nuxt/postcss8/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js): Error: No parent could be found at /home/my-name/Code/project-folder/assets/css/tailwind.scss:85:1 at findParent (/home/my-name/Code/project-folder/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/lib/substituteClassApplyAtRules.js:262:9) at.....
```

If anyone knows, please help.

Comment: If you only need nesting, take a look at [Tailwind Nesting](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#nesting)

Comment: I have already. But as I am using Nuxt, I haven't got a postcss.config.js file.

Comment: In Tailwind the recommended method is building components using the utility classes where you need reusability. Relying on complex classes in Tailwind is an antipattern and specifically advised against in the docs https://tailwindcss.com/docs/extracting-components . If you're into BEM you'll live a happier life just using CSS/SCSS, if you dig Tailwind you should try following it's patterns.

Comment: @JHeth you should answer the question, I think this is the solution

Comment: Same here, have you found a solution @Maxime?